# Meilisearch error when I use where() statement to filter results is returned by meilisearch

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I am using Meilisearch as driver for laravel scout.

My codes in controller:

```
public function search(SearchInArticlesRequest $request)
    {
        $query = $request->s;
        $articles = Article::search($query)
            ->where('article.status', '=', 'published')
            ->where('article.publish_date_time', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
            ->paginate(20);
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'message' => 'articles_were_returned',
            'entire' => [
                'articles' => $articles
            ]
        ]);
}
```

My `Article` model:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Searchable;

    protected $table = 'article';
    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        return $this->only(['id', 'title', 'body' , 'slug']);
    }
}
```

My `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/scout": "^9.2",
        "meilisearch/meilisearch-php": "^0.18.3",
    },
```

The problem is: When is call the controller method i mentioned in above lines, The error below occur:

`Json deserialize error: unknown field filters, expected one of q, offset, limit, attributesToRetrieve, attributesToCrop, cropLength, attributesToHighlight, matches, filter, facetsDistribution at line 1 column 23`

Comment: show `dd($request->s)`

Comment: I do it. it prints search query.

Comment: try to `search(['q' => $request->s])`

Comment: It returns the error below:
`MeiliSearch\\Endpoints\\Indexes::rawSearch(): Argument #1 ($query) must be of type ?string, array given, called in /var/www/liaratech/vendor/laravel/scout/src/Engines/MeiliSearchEngine.php on line 140`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an SDK which for now is only compatible with stable v0.20 with a v0.21 RC of MeiliSearch